# Reordering Multigroup Lollipop chart by highest variable value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder my chart to show the variable with the highest max value to the lowest. I initially tried to make a new variable and use the fct_inorder from the forcats but I couldn't make it work. I think I am having a hard time because I have the facilies on the same stem, but that the most attractive to me instead of separating them by panel.

My data:

```
Kappa_viz <- structure(list(vname = c("Variable 1", "Variable 2", "Variable 3", 
                         "Variable 4", "Variable 5", "Variable 6", "Variable 7", "Variable 8", 
                         "Variable 9", "Variable 10", "Variable 11", "Variable 12", "Variable 13", 
                         "Variable 14", "Variable 15", "Variable 16", "Variable 1", "Variable 2", 
                         "Variable 3", "Variable 4", "Variable 5", "Variable 6", "Variable 7", 
                         "Variable 8", "Variable 9", "Variable 10", "Variable 11", "Variable 12", 
                         "Variable 13", "Variable 14", "Variable 15", "Variable 16", "Variable 1", 
                         "Variable 2", "Variable 3", "Variable 4", "Variable 5", "Variable 6", 
                         "Variable 7", "Variable 8", "Variable 9", "Variable 10", "Variable 11", 
                         "Variable 12", "Variable 13", "Variable 14", "Variable 15", "Variable 16"), 
               facname = c("Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 1", 
                           "Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 1", 
                           "Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 1", 
                           "Facility 1", "Facility 1", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", 
                           "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", 
                           "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", 
                           "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 2", "Facility 3", "Facility 3", 
                           "Facility 3", "Facility 3", "Facility 3", "Facility 3", "Facility 3", 
                           "Facility 3", "Facility 3", "Facility 3", "Facility 3", "Facility 3", 
                           "Facility 3", "Facility 3", "Facility 3", "Facility 3"), 
               values = c(0.71, 
                          0.22, 0.13, 0.6, 0.22, 0.12, 0.16, 0.1, 0.97, 0.84, 0.53, 0.04, 
                          1, 0.92, 0.55, 0.1, 0.09, 0.84, 0.4, 0.25, 0.53, 0.49, 0.62, 
                          0.55, 0.52, 1, 0.96, 0.9, 0.55, 1, 0.21, 0.51, 0.81, 0.1, 0.63, 
                          0.92, 0.07, 0.55, 0.84, 0.81, 0.27, 0.93, 0.7, 0.05, 0.43, 0.78, 
                          0.47, 0.92)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -48L))
```

Here is the code for the chart. It generates what I want, but I am stuck trying to rearrange the graph.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(Kappa_viz, 
            aes(y = vname, x = values, fill = facname)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20))+
  ggtitle("Correlation by Facility")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20,hjust=0.5))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = vname, xend = values, yend = vname), 
               color = "grey50", size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(color=facname), size = 5, alpha=0.7) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Kappa Interpretation")+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none")

print(p)
```

Chart produced:

[image: Lolliipop chart]

I tried creating a new variable and using `fct_inorder` from forcat but I was unsuccessful. I  lost the code for that unfortunately so I do not have it. The code ran successfully, but the order of the chart remained unchanged. I tried to reorder it by making an Order variable and ordering the values by an assigment of 1-16 to indicate highest, but since I have it accross three groups I believe the variable I made is the issue.

Comment: You guessed correctly, it's your variable values causing the issue. Your vname column is a character type. Therefore, your variables are being sorted alphanumerically. Add a leading 0 to all your single digit variables e.g. change "variable 1" to "variable 01" and so on. This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting your data frame from highest to lowest value, then apply `fct_inorder()` so that vname's levels follow the first appearance of each variable.

After that, if I'm reading your question right & you want max-to-min from top to bottom (instead of the other way around), reverse the levels using `fct_rev()`, since ggplot's y-axis is typically arranged with the highest value on top and the lowest at the bottom.

```
Kappa_viz_new <- Kappa_viz %>%
  arrange(desc(values)) %>%
  mutate(vname = forcats::fct_inorder(vname) %>%
           forcats::fct_rev())
```

Result:

[image: plot]